# How to find when stick is released

Tags: java, xbox360, jinput

I have problem to check when stick in my gamepad (XBox) is released.
With buttons when I press the first I get pollData = 1.0 and after releasing it I get pollData = 0.0.

With analog sticks I don't have such event like pollData = 0.0

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I think you have to get the x and y axis of the joystick to see if they are at 0%.  I believe you can call the method `getXAxisPercentage()` to return that.  This blog might have some info that might help:  http://theuzo007.wordpress.com/2012/09/02/joystick-in-java-with-jinput/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you already have the axis as a

```
Component component;
```

(to be sure that it is an axis by testing

```
if(component.isAnalog())
```

then you can get the position by calling

```
component.getPollData()
```

The returned value will be between -1 and 1. -1 being left/bottom, +1 being right/top, depending on whether component.getIdentifier() equals Component.Identifier.Axis.X or Component.Identifier.Axis.Y.

So you could do something like

```
bool xReleased = false, yReleased = false;
Component[] components = controller.getComponents();
for(Component component : components) {
    if(component.isAnalog()) { //test that controller is analog
        Identifier id = component.getIdentifier();
        float axisPosition = component.getPollData(); //range: -1 to 1
        if(id == Component.Identifier.Axis.X && axisPosition == 0)
            xReleased = true;
        if(id == Component.Identifier.Axis.Y && axisPosition == 0)
            yReleased = true;
    }
}

if(xReleased && yReleased) {
    //do something...
}
```